# Cannot use Httpclient-osgi-4.5.2. Missing Requirements

Tags: java, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am developing a OSGi app using Apache Felix as runtime. I use Maven to download httpclient-osgi. I have installed the bundle in the framework. But it results in the following exception.

It seems that I am missing a bundle that exports org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient. But I really have no idea which bundle would export that package.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [3](R 3.0): missing requirement [org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [3](R 3.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.cm)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [3](R 3.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.cm)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984)
at compilerMain.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a bundle that exports that package org.osgi.service.cm. This means that httpclient needs the ConfigurationAdmin spec and possibly also a running instance. The easiest way to solve this is to install felix ConfigurationAdmin.

Comment: It works. Thank you. I am very new to osgi. So sometimes I can't handle problem like missing requirements. Is it "osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.cm" the part showing the name of the missing package?

Comment: Yes. If you use plain felix right now it might be a good idea to look into either bndtools or Apache Karaf. Both help a lot in different ways to get your OSGi projects working more easily.